# Amazon SP-API - Amazon Custom, Text customisation

Tags: amazon-mws, amazon-selling-partner-api

I'm trying to find some information that would detail the process of creating custom product listings on Amazon, via the SP-API (or MWS API).

I can see information on how to retrieve the custom detail once an order has been placed: https://sellercentral.amazon.co.uk/help/hub/reference/G201822830 I just read in either the order response or call the GET_FLAT_FILE_ACTIONABLE_ORDER_DATA report.

However, I'm looking for a way to list stuff on Amazon via the API and not the bulk upload: https://sellercentral.amazon.co.uk/help/hub/reference/GQMSBWT4DK5ARMXL

> The bulk customisation tool allows you to apply customisations to numerous ASINs at the same time through an Excel file. To begin the bulk upload process, you will need to 1) create a base ASIN, 2) apply customisations, 3) generate and download the template, 4) enter bulk information, and 5) upload the feed and submit customisations for bulk application. Below are the instructions for the steps outlined above.

Anyone that has some information on if this is possible and some documentation for either SP-API or MWS API, would be appreciated.